# get val of node in array by select value

Tags: jquery

Having this array

```
  var eventsDates = {
    "0" :["11-10-2012","21-10-2012","28-10-2012","25-11-2012","15-12-2012"],
    "10":["11-10-2012"],
    "11":["21-10-2012","28-10-2012"],
    "12":["25-11-2012","15-12-2012"]
  }
```

I need to save in variable certain group of dates by a select like this

```
<select>
<option value="0">all dates</option>
<option value="10">baseball</option>
<option value="11">hokey</option>
<option value="12">basket</option>
</select>
```

Any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to access the array value by select value you can try-

```
eventsDates[$("select").val()]
```